# formatting the text in choicemenu

Tags: forms

In the following example, I would like to have 'No' in red.  However, Latex does not compile the file. I wonder what can be done to color code the choices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\ChoiceMenu[combo,name=tmp]{}{Yes, {\color{red}No}, N/A}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's entered in the box is not typeset by TeX, so using `\color{red}` will do nothing, even after loading `xcolor` for supporting the command.

Comment: @egreg Is there any alternative?